# More generic os.path.basename for os.walk()?

Tags: python, filepath, os.walk

`os.walk()` `yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#files-and-directories)).

If I want to use certain parts of dirpath, is there a more robust way than splitting on `\`?

In a path like **"C:\top_folder\project\somethingelse"** I currently do `dirpath.split('\\')[2] # project` but if the folder structure changes, I'd need to change that line and I wouldn't always know if the folder structure changes until my scripts break.

Is there a way to dissect `dirpath` to be more specific, similar to `os.path.basename`, just more generically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pathlib does this in a very nice way;

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent

It's considered the modern way to work with Python and paths.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it seems that doesn't exist. Your answer is closest to what I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, you want to get the parent `"dirpath"` which contains `"somethingelse"`. You could simply do
`dirpath.split('\\')[-2]`
It will not be affected even if the directory structure changes before `dirpath`